# What is the definition of the Sobolev space $H^1(\Omega)$ with $\Omega=(0,1)\times\mathbb{T}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Denote the 1-D torus as $\mathbb{T}:=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Using Fourier series, one can define $H^1(\mathbb{T})$ (see for instance [this note from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#The_case_p_.3D_2)). On the other hand, the definition of $H^1(U)$ with $U=(0,1)$ is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Multidimensional_case).

Here is my **question**:

> How should one define the Sobolev space $H^1(\Omega)$ with $\Omega=(0,1)\times\mathbb{T}$?

---

[Added for clarification:] For function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, I mean $\Omega=(0,1)\times \mathbb{T}$, not $(0,1)^2$ nor $\mathbb{T}^2$. Hence $f$ here is periodic in *one* component.

Comment: The closure of $C^\infty((0,1)^2)$ for the $H^1$ norm. Otherwise, you can symmetrize $(0,1)^2$ into $(-1,1)^2$ and obtain a $2$-periodic absolutely continuous function whose Fourier series is well-defined. The symmetries tell us its Fourier series will have only $\cos$ terms : $f(x,y) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty  \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,m} \cos(\pi n x)\cos(\pi m y)$ where $\sum_{m=1}^\infty  \sum_{n=1}^\infty m^2 n^2 |a_{n,m}|^2 < \infty$

Comment: @Jack: What do you mean by "how should one define"? There are various versions of Sobolev spaces which are useful for different purposes ($H^1, H^1_0$, etc). Do you have any application in mind? Are there specific functions you want $H^1(\Omega)$ to include?